# Program crashes when using cv::findContours with Qt Gui

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I have been stuck with this issue for days;

I created a Qt console project, connected it with OpenCV and everything was working just fine;

I created a Qt Gui project, added a button and copied the same code from the previous project in the button's slot, I got a windows segFault and program exited with code -1073741819.

So I used the debugger to detect the problem and it turned out to be at the use of function `cv::threshold`.

I changed it and instead used `cv::Canny` but then I got the same problem with `cv::findContours` !

The strange thing is that when I called the button's 'MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()'
in the windows' constructor it worked!!!

here's debugger output:

```
0   cv::thresh_8u(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&, unsigned char, unsigned char, int)  C:\OpenCV2.4\OpenMinGw\install\bin\libopencv_imgproc240.dll 0   0x62b2c624  
1   cv::_InputArray::getMat(int) const  C:\OpenCV2.4\OpenMinGw\install\bin\libopencv_core240.dll    0   0x65c1a838  
2   ??      0   0x00000000
```

and here's the function where I get the error (which I got from OpenCV tutorials):

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(){

    Mat src; Mat src_gray;
    int thresh = 100;
    RNG rng(12345);
    Mat canny_output;

    vector<vector<Point> > contours;

    /// Load source image and convert it to gray
    src = imread( "hat-10.bmp", 1 );

    cvtColor( src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
    blur( src_gray, src_gray, Size(3,3) );

    /// Detect edges using canny
    Canny( src_gray, canny_output, thresh, thresh*2, 3 );
    qDebug("Ok 1");

    /// Find contours
    if(cv::sum(src_gray).val[0] > 0.0){

        qDebug("Ok 2");
        cv::findContours( src_gray, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE );
        /// Draw contours
        Mat drawing = Mat::zeros( src_gray.size(), CV_8UC3 );
        for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
        {
            Scalar color = Scalar( rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0,255), rng.uniform(0,255) );
            drawContours( drawing, contours, i, color, 2);//, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point() );
        }
        /// Show in a window
        imshow( "Contours", drawing);

    }
```

Using:

- Windows 7 x64
- OpenCV 2.4.0 compiled using mingw 4.1.0
- Qt Creator 2.0.0 Based on Qt 4.7.0 (32 bit)

**Edit:**

here's a shorter version of my code :

```
void MainWindow::on_toolButton_clicked(){
 std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;

/// Load source image and convert it to gray
Mat src = imread( "C:/Users/poste/L3 ISIL/PFE Licence/new bmp/hat-10.bmp", 1);
// my image is already a binary one
Mat canny_output(src.size(), src.type());

Canny(src,canny_output,100,200,3);

imshow("Source",  canny_output); // here image is displayed before crash
waitKey(500);

/// Find contours
findContours(canny_output, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE );

}
```

in console mode, there's no problem. when called from GUI app constructor there's also no problem.
It only crashes when actually clicking on the button.

**edit:** 
I took a screenshot ![here]https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LyeF.png
`canny_output` was displayed which means image was loaded.

Uploaded project [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?a2wntt7eaqxid7d)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used function Qtconcurrent::run() and everything started working.
Even though this isn't a permanent (nor a good) solution; this is all I could come up with.

I'm still open to other answers though.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that the image that you want to threshold is really a gray scaled image. Show it in another window after Thresholding.

Do that before cv::FindContours:

```
cvThreshold(originalImage,resultingImage,100,100,CV_THRESH_BINARY)
```

also change that:

```
vector<vector<Point> > contours;

to:

vector<vector<cv::Point2f> > contours;
```

Comment: when I changed `cv::Point` to `cv::Point2f` I got 
`Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.`
as for `threshold`, I used it and then went back to Canny (since it gives the same results)

Here's the output image when I call the function from constructor
![Picture](http://img11.imageshack.us/img11/5268/outputxv.png)

Obviously the code works.
Problem is, why doesn't it work when I click on QButton?

Comment: Please upload the sample project I will test.

Comment: imgread fails, check the bps for the image, you used 1 which means it is a 3 channel image! and the attached image is grayscale!

Comment: Ok. I changed it to   `Mat src = imread( "hat-10.bmp", 0)`
and did this : 
`Mat canny_output(src.size(), CV_8U)`
and it's still the same.
Did it work for you?

Comment: If imread fails, and src is empty, then there is a problem with imread function, you may have a problem with the picture itself.

Comment: I added the check @karlphillip recommended 
 `if (!src.empty()) { //load image etc etc}
else qDebug("error");` and I still had the crash.
besides if the problem was with the image, it wouldn't have worked when called in constructor but it did.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/// Load source image and convert it to gray
Mat src = imread( "hat-10.bmp", 1 );

Mat src_gray(src.size(), CV_8U);
cvtColor( src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );

blur( src_gray, src_gray, Size(3,3) );

//Apply threshold
cv::Mat thres_output(src_gray.size(), src_gray.type());
cv::threshold(src_gray, thres_output, 100, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
qDebug("Ok 1");
```

OpenCV docs have a full demo on [Basic Thresholding Operations](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html#code).

**EDIT:**

After carefully reviewing your code and comments, I think I know what's going on: these problems might be happening because **`imread()` can't access the specified file**. This makes the function return an empty `Mat`. To check if this is the case, simply do:

```
Mat src = imread( "hat-10.bmp", 1 );
if (src.empty())
{
    std::cout << "!!! imread failed to open image\n";
    return;
}
```

The reason why it happens is because Qt Creator builds the **.exe** of the project in a separate folder, so when the application runs, it tries to load the image from the directory where the .exe was launched, and it fails because the image isn't there.

When calling `imread()` remember to pass the FULL PATH to the file. See if that fixes the issue.

**EDIT**:

Remember to convert the image to binary before feeding it to `findContours()`:

```
// Convert from 32F to 8U
cv::Mat binary_img;
canny_output.convertTo(binary_img, CV_8U);

std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
cv::findContours(binary_img, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
```

Comment: I though that the `cv::threshold()` was causing the crash, and that was what it made you use Canny.

Comment: Yes, it used to cause a crash but not any more (I had to check my PATH directory)
problem is : this code works fine in command line but crashes in GUI;
any ideas?

Comment: Updated post.
It didn't solve the problem but debug output changed (?)

Comment: None of the functions listed in the new debug are related to OpenCV. You need to pinpoint which of the OpenCV calls causes the crash.

Comment: It seems to be `findContours` because the comment after the function doesn't show and instead Qt exited with code -1073741819
After looking for it,  I found that this code shows that I'm trying to access memory that doesn't exist.
but when I call this same function in window's constructor, it works like a charm!

Comment: Updated answer, please test this new tip.

Comment: It still doesn't work!
Could it probably be a Qt problem?
since it works in a Qt Console application but not in a GUI one.

Comment: Nope, there's something else going on. The problem is in your code. I can only help you further if you share a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I edited the code to a shorter one.
I have the same problem though

Comment: Pretty sure you should be reffering to it as `C:\\Users\\poste\\L3 ISIL\\PFE Licence\\new bmp\\hat-10.bmp`. I can't help you if you ignore my previous tips. ALWAYS code safely: add the check to verify if the image was loaded successfully.

Comment: Edited again. I took a screenshot